# Issue with Wordpress Preview Link for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, graphql, headless

I've encountered a strange issue, possibly a WordPress bug.

I'm creating a headless WordPress installation with a Nuxt as front end.

I'm using WP Engine Headless and WP GraphQL plugins.

Everything seems to be working fine

I've registered a custom post type and created a new post.

The permalink generated seems correct.

[image: see below permalink generating correnctly using the post type and the post name]

The preview link is missing a slash, which generates a 404 page.

[image: see the URL is wrong, a slash is missing between post type and post name]

Here is my code:

```
public function standard_form_posttype() {

    // Set UI labels for Custom Post Type   
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => __( 'Standard Forms', 'Post Type General Name', 'vg-core' ),
        'singular_name'       => __( 'Standard Form', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'vg-core' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Standard Forms', 'vg-core' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Standard Forms', 'vg-core' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Standard Form', 'vg-core' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Standard Form', 'vg-core' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'vision-green-core' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Standard Form', 'vg-core' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Standard Form', 'vg-core' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Standard Form', 'vg-core' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'vg-core' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'vg-core' ),
    );
        
// Set other options for Custom Post Type
        
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'standard-forms', 'vg-core' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Standard forms configurations', 'vg-core' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
        'supports'            => array( 'title','author', 'revisions'),
        // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy. 
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'category'),
        /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
        * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
        * is like Posts.
        */ 
    //     'hierarchical'        => true,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
    //     'show_in_menu'        => true,
    //     'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    //     'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    //     'menu_position'       => 5,
    //     'can_export'          => true,
    //     'has_archive'         => true,
    //     'exclude_from_search' => true,
    //     'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability'          => 'post',
    //     'show_in_rest'        => true,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-forms',
        'show_in_graphql' => true,
        'graphql_single_name' => 'standard',
        'graphql_plural_name' => 'standards',
    );
        
    // Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'standardtmp', $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
     
}
```

I've been dealing with this issue for a good while, if you have any idea on how to solve it it would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Salvo